# Redistribution fails for large messages in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, amqp, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.19.1, and I'm facing an issue in a 6-node (3 masters) cluster where redistribution is failing for large messages with the below warning logs:

```
23:35:05,551 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222303: Redistribution by Redistributor[TEST_QUEUE/2244] of messageID = 196,950,715 failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not supported with Large Messages
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.AMQPLargeMessage.getData(AMQPLargeMessage.java:311) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.AMQPMessage.anyMessageAnnotations(AMQPMessage.java:1374) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.AMQPMessage.hasScheduledDeliveryTime(AMQPMessage.java:1352) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.processRoute(PostOfficeImpl.java:1499) [artemis-server-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.Redistributor$1.run(Redistributor.java:169) [artemis-server-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_322]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_322]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
```

Later I see broker is removing consumers with below warning since properties=null:

```
00:10:28,280 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222151: removing consumer which did not handle a message, consumer=ServerConsumerImpl [id=57, filter=null, binding=LocalQueueBinding [address=TEST_QUEUE, queue=QueueImpl[name=TEST_QUEUE, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=localhost], temp=false]@9c000b7, filter=null, name=TEST_QUEUE, clusterName=TEST_QUEUE1e359f55-c92b-11ec-b908-005056a3af3f]], message=Reference[157995028]:RELIABLE:AMQPLargeMessage( [durable=true, messageID=157995028, address=TEST_QUEUE, size=0, scanningStatus=SCANNED, applicationProperties={VER=05, trackingId=62701757c80c3004d037ded6}, messageAnnotations={}, properties=null, extraProperties = TypedProperties[_AMQ_AD=TEST_QUEUE]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Array must not be empty or null
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.CompositeReadableBuffer.append(CompositeReadableBuffer.java:688) [proton-j-0.33.10.jar:]
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.DeliveryImpl.send(DeliveryImpl.java:345) [proton-j-0.33.10.jar:]
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.SenderImpl.send(SenderImpl.java:74) [proton-j-0.33.10.jar:]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.ProtonServerSenderContext$LargeMessageDeliveryContext.deliverInitialPacket(ProtonServerSenderContext.java:686) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.ProtonServerSenderContext$LargeMessageDeliveryContext.deliver(ProtonServerSenderContext.java:587) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
```

I have 6 consumers for this queue if one message out of many (let's say 1,000) is large - it should process other messages but, the processing is stopped completely with 0 consumers on the queue.

Comment: What is version `2.19.1-1`? Have you tried with the latest release (i.e. 2.22.0)? Do you have a way to reproduce this problem that you could share?

Comment: I tried with 4 nodes (2 masters). En-queued large message of around 250K characters (260 KB) on one master and consumers pointed to 2nd master. I'm using the 2.19.1-1 release and have not tried with 2.22.

Comment: What is version `2.19.1-1`? There is no such release for ActiveMQ Artemis. Do you mean `2.19.1`? Can you try `2.22.0`? Can you post your producer code?

Comment: The version is 2.19.1 I shared RPM version my bad. Tried with 2.22.0 same behavior. Also, Producer is just a camel route with Artemis component ( JmsComponent bean created with org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory)  I can not share complete code. I'm not sure why you need a producer, it has nothing to do with a producer you can use any producer - the error clearly says the issue in re-distribution within master nodes

Comment: The message redistributor takes the message _as it was sent_ so although it's not necessarily required having the producer code is helpful to know exactly how the message is being sent (what annotations are set, what exactly message body is, what client library and which version is being used, etc.). It can also greatly speed up reproducing this issue which means you might get a fix sooner.

Comment: Also, the message in question is an instance of `AMQPMessage` which likely means the message was _sent_ using an AMQP client so it appears that I can't "use any producer" as you assert.

Comment: It does look like a bug indeed.. if you could open a JIRA? if there's a reproducer even better.

Comment: @GND if you could follow the discussion on JIRA. I could not reproduce it.. so a reproducer would definitely help.

Comment: I had posted the wrong link on my previous comment, here is the right link:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3837

Comment: Most likely you used an older version of the broker to send the message... restarted the broker with older data and the broker did not have some stuff in the journal that's now used in the new version. I will need some extra info so I would appreciate some follow up on the JIRA.

Comment: @Clebert Suconic: The log in the question is from 2.19 but I could see the same issue with 2.22

Comment: @GND please followup on the JIRA. I cannot reproduce the issue in any way... the server always has the message parsed before I called hasScheduledTime... 

perhaps you have a plugin that would re-encode the message? or you have some special producer in C++ or something like that that's generating some odd message? Please.. lets follow up that on the JIRA as stack overflow is not meant for this.. after figured out we can add an answer here.

Comment: lets move the discussion to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3837 and come back here after figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send large messages, within the first block sent the large message is parsed for properties. Most likely you are using large properties in a way the server is not being able to parse the first few bytes of the message. You should avoid using large properties and let the large portion only for the client.

We tried following up with many tests on this JIRA, and the only plausible scenarios would be through large properties, or some incomplete message your client is generating in a way the server can't parse it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3837

if you provide a reproducer showing how the property is failing to be parsed we will follow up with a possible fix.

Please move any discussion regarding this to the JIRA. It could be a bug caused by your anti-pattern.